# Django BooleanField as radio buttons?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Is there a widget in Django 1.0.2 to render a `models.BooleanField` as two radio buttons instead of a checkbox?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You could do this by overriding the field definition in the ModelForm:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    boolfield = forms.TypedChoiceField(
                   coerce=lambda x: x == 'True',
                   choices=((False, 'False'), (True, 'True')),
                   widget=forms.RadioSelect
                )

    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, because the coerce=bool is being passed a string value, and not the boolean value and bool("False") => True.  So I had to write a custom coerce function to take the string value and convert to bool, then it worked.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Should really be updated since, as @dar notes, this actually will NOT work since `bool('False')` =>  `True`.

Comment: Shouldn't the choices be `(('False', False), ('True', True))`? In other words, shouldn't they be the other way around?

Comment: Just came across this, and wanted to note the update to this answer works.  Per [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2723#comment:18): `TypedChoiceField(coerce=lambda x: x =='True', choices=((False, 'No'), (True, 'Yes')), widget=forms.RadioSelect)`

Comment: This way the field is improperly shown in form.changed_data, because coerce is used when comparing form input value and initial value. Passing bool True to coerce results in False and "True" from form results passed to coerce results in True, therefore is mentioned as changed_data. I solved it with following coerce: coerce=lambda x: ((x != 'False' and x is not False) or False)

Comment: how the options can be displayed yes and no horizontally

Answer (score 96):

Django 1.2 has added the "widgets" Meta option for modelforms:

In your models.py, specify the "choices" for your boolean field:

```
BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))

class MyModel(models.Model):
    yes_or_no = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
```

Then, in your forms.py, specify the RadioSelect widget for that field:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'yes_or_no': forms.RadioSelect
        }
```

I've tested this with a SQLite db, which also stores booleans as 1/0 values, and it seems to work fine without a custom coerce function.

Comment: The cleanest and most "Django"y solution by far. Thanks!

Comment: This is great. I would modify it slightly to allow localized versions of 'Yes' and 'No' by using `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _` and updating `BOOL_CHOICES` to be:

`BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, _('Yes')), (False, _('No')))`

Comment: I think the extra code to localize it would distract from the point.  An exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Simpler with choices defined in the form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833454

Comment: For me, the radio select ended up with a third option labeled "
 ---------". Why is that?

Answer (score 30):

Modifying Daniel Roseman's answer a bit, you could fix the bool("False") = True problem succinctly by just using ints instead:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    boolfield = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=lambda x: bool(int(x)),
                   choices=((0, 'False'), (1, 'True')),
                   widget=forms.RadioSelect
                )

class Meta:
     model = MyModel
```

Comment: This isn't working on my edit form. The current value of the field is not pulled from the model. I used eternicode's answer instead.

Answer (score 21):

Here's the simplest approach I could find (I'm using Django 1.5):

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    yes_no = forms.BooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(choices=[(True, 'Yes'), 
                                                            (False, 'No')]))
```

Comment: This should the proper answer.

Comment: Verifying this solution works, but see the [note in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield). You need to set required=False on the field.

Answer (score 13):

In Django 1.6, the following worked for me:

```
class EmailSettingsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = EmailSetting
        fields = ['setting']
        widgets = {'setting': RadioSelect(choices=[
            (True, 'Keep updated with emails.'),
            (False, 'No, don\'t email me.')             
        ])}
```

Answer (score 6):

Same as @eternicode's answer, but without modifying the model:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    yes_no = forms.RadioSelect(choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')])

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {'boolfield': yes_no}
```

I think this only works in Django 1.2+

Comment: What does `boolfield` refer to?

Comment: @DataGreed Replace that with the name of your field.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick & dirty coerce function using lambda, that gets around the "False" -> True problem:

```
...
boolfield = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=lambda x: x and (x.lower() != 'false'),
...
```

Answer (score 5):

As there is problem in @Daniel Roseman answer, bool('False') --> True, so now i have combined two answers here to make one solution.

```py
def boolean_coerce(value):
    # value is received as a unicode string
    if str(value).lower() in ("1", "true"):
        return True
    elif str(value).lower() in ("0", "false"):
        return False
    return None


class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    boolfield = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        coerce=boolean_coerce,
        choices=((False, "False"), (True, "True")),
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
    )


class Meta:
    model = MyModel
```

Now this will work :)

Answer (score 3):

Also remember that MySQL uses tinyint for Boolean, so True/False are actually 1/0. I used this coerce function:

```
def boolean_coerce(value):
    # value is received as a unicode string
    if str(value).lower() in ( '1', 'true' ):
        return True
    elif str(value).lower() in ( '0', 'false' ):
        return False
    return None
```

Answer (score 3):

An other solution:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def RadioBoolean(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.update({
        'widget': forms.RadioSelect,
        'choices': [
            ('1', _('yes')),
            ('0', _('no')),
        ],
        'coerce': lambda x: bool(int(x)) if x.isdigit() else False,
    })
    return forms.TypedChoiceField(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

update for django version 3.0:

```
BOOLEAN_CHOICES = (('1', 'True label'), ('0', 'False label'))
  # Filtering fields
    True_or_false_question = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="Some Label3",
  # uses items in BOOLEAN_CHOICES
        choices = BOOLEAN_CHOICES,
        widget = forms.RadioSelect
    )
```

it gives a bullet point button list, i dont know how to make it not do that

Comment: STyle the <li> items with `list-style-type: none;` to remove the disc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type