# ManyToMany in Admin - URL's to objects instand standard widget?

Tags: python, django

How to display url to objects from Many To Many relation instead standard widget?

For example url's to `Author` objects here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think one way is to overwrite **str** method of Author.

Another is to change widget for that field [Django: Admin: changing the widget of the field in Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337304/django-admin-changing-the-widget-of-the-field-in-admin) , my prefered method.

Answer (score 0):

Django admin offers to properties that change the way `m2m` fields act in the admin: `filter_vertical` and `filter_horizontal` use them like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('author',)
```

or replace with `filter_vertical` use one or the other on the same field.