# Django model field isn't showing up correctly in the django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

The PtoHistory Model:

```
class PtoHistory(models.Model):
    LEAVE_CHOICES = (
        (True, 'PTO'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Jury Duty'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Voting'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Military Leave'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Bereavement'), #is chargeable?
        (True, 'Emergency'), #is chargeable?
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    leave_end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    leave_type = models.BooleanField(choices=LEAVE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**The problem:**

Whenever I change the "leave_type" inside of the django admin, for example, to "Emergency" it will show up as "PTO" in the django admin because they are both True but PTO comes up first in the tuple so it shows "PTO" in the django admin. The same thing happens for all of the options that are False. If "Military Leave" is selected and saved, when viewed in the django admin it shows up as "Jury Duty" because "Jury Duty" is the first false in the tuple.

[dango admin pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEgXM.png)

**What I want to happen:**

If the user chooses "Bereavement", I want "Bereavement" to show up in the django admin as the choice that was selected and I want it to correspond to a False value meaning that it won't count against the employee's PTO hours.

I hope my desired output is understood and I can provide more clarification or code snippets if it is needed. Honestly, I don't even know if I'm going about it in the correct way. So if I need to restructure my model in any way I would appreciate some direction.

After sleeping on it, I'm thinking a python dictionary would be a great way to go about solving this problem where I could save key/value pairs but I'm not aware of a django model field type "dictionary".

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a `CharField` so it would be much simpler for you're user to choose his way of *Live Type*, something like this.

```
class PtoHistory(models.Model):
    LEAVE_CHOICES = (
        ('pto', 'PTO'), #is chargeable?
        ('jury duty', 'Jury Duty'), #is chargeable?
        ('voting', 'Voting'), #is chargeable?
        ('military leave', 'Military Leave'), #is chargeable?
        ('bereavement', 'Bereavement'), #is chargeable?
        ('emergency', 'Emergency'), #is chargeable?
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    leave_end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    leave_type = models.CharField(max_length=225, choices=LEAVE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I would define `LEAVE_CHOICE` outside models, and after in your `forms.py` you define radio button widget, you have something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3961084/4107823)

```
LEAVE_CHOICES = (
        (True, 'PTO'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Jury Duty'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Voting'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Military Leave'), #is chargeable?
        (False, 'Bereavement'), #is chargeable?
        (True, 'Emergency'), #is chargeable?
    )

class PtoHistory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    leave_end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    leave_type = models.BooleanField(choices=LEAVE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
class PtoHistoryModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['leave_start_data', 'leave_end_data', 'leave_type']
        widgets = {
            'leave_type': forms.RadioSelect
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PetarP. How would I make each leave type correspond to a true or false value? Is this possible? The way I have it now the user gets a drop down list of the choices so you're solution doesn't really change the way they will interact with it on the front end.

Comment: that is related to `boolean` field only, here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3961084/4107823) on how you can use `RadioSelect` widget in your `forms.py`

Comment: you're radio widget suggestion isn't having the desired effect as laid out in "What I want to happen" in the question. If I choose "Emergency" it still shows up as "PTO" in the django admin. The only difference is the dropdown choice menu vs the radio widgets.

Comment: You should experiment more with this, I think you're `boolean` is not wright, I can try and conjure something later. I would go with first example, because it simpler, if I understand it right you want to see why is someone absent

Comment: Yes that is correct. Even though the user chooses "Emergency" it shows up as "PTO" in the django admin because "PTO" is the first True value in the choice tuple. Here is the project on github if you'd like to try it out.

https://github.com/FlashBanistan/Django-PTO_APP